# Apply static resource style to UIElement created in converter

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter, uielement, staticresource

I am binding the `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl` to a `Textbox` and then using a converter to create `UIElement` objects based on the `Text` property of the `Textbox`.  I also have a static resource style that I want to apply to the elements I create.

The problem I'm having is how to set the style of the items created in the converter to the static resource since I don't have access to the static resources in my converter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `StaticResource` in the `Converter` you could send the `Style` as `ConverterParameter`.

If you're already using the `ConverterParameter` you could make the `Converter` derive from `DependencyObject`, add a Dependency Property and set it to the `Style` on the creation of the `Converter`.

But the easiest solution is probably to use `DynamicResource` instead if you know the key of the resource.

The following Xaml

```
<UIElement Style="{DynamicResource styleKey}" />
```

is equivalent to the following C# code

```
myUIElement.SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, "styleKey");
```

Comment: That works great thanks.  I also tried to set the ItemTemplate on my ItemsControl, but I think I had something incorrect somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Mission impossible! :) you can use ConverterParameter as your static resource, I think. and all will be ok!